# @Autowired field null when executing production code via integration tests

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, grpc-java

Bit of a weird one that I've been scratching my head over for the past few days. I have a JPA repository that is field injected into a service class. Is works perfectly when running the server and sending a request via a client but when the code is executed via integration tests the field injected class (CustomerRepository ) is always null.

I've tried various advice via the internet but I've not found a similar scenario to mine, any help would be much appreciated

Service class

```
@GRpcService
public class CustomerService extends CustomerServiceGrpc.CustomerServiceImplBase {

    @Autowired
    private CustomerRepository repository;

    @Override
    public void createCustomer(CreateCustomerRequest request, StreamObserver<CreateCustomerResponse> responseObserver) {

        final CustomerDao convertedDao = ProtoToDaoConverter.convertCustomerRequestProtoToCustomerDao(request);

        repository.save(convertedDao);

        responseObserver.onNext(CreateCustomerResponse.newBuilder().setSuccess(true).build());
        responseObserver.onCompleted();
    }
}
```

Integration test

```
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
@SpringBootTest
public class CustomerServiceIT {

    @Rule
    private final GrpcCleanupRule grpcCleanup = new GrpcCleanupRule();

    @Test
    public void something() throws IOException {

        String serverName = InProcessServerBuilder.generateName();

        // Create a server, add service, start, and register for automatic graceful shutdown.
        grpcCleanup.register(InProcessServerBuilder
                .forName(serverName).directExecutor().addService(new CustomerService()).build().start());

        customerServiceGrpc.CustomerServiceBlockingStub blockingStub = CustomerServiceGrpc.newBlockingStub(
                // Create a client channel and register for automatic graceful shutdown.
                grpcCleanup.register(InProcessChannelBuilder.forName(serverName).directExecutor().build()));

        final CreateCustomerRequest request = CreateCustomerRequest.newBuilder().setFirstName("Simon").setSecondName("Brown").setRole("Product Developer").build();

        final CreateCustomerResponse response = blockingStub.createCustomer(request);
    }

}
```

Comment: How do you configure injection in your integration test?

Comment: No external config, using @SpringBootTest for instance.

Comment: then read Erunafailaro's answer. There must be differences between test and run config, or it would work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In test you invoke `new CustomerService()`. You create an object by itself, not via spring. I guess you should create a field in test class

`@Autowired private final CustomerService customerService`

and pass it in 
`grpcCleanup.register(InProcessServerBuilder
                .forName(serverName).directExecutor().addService(customerService).build().start());`

Comment: Yes, you were right! Don't know how I missed that but there was another way of instantiating CustomerService by the gRPC framework so it can be managed by Spring. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Mockito](https://site.mockito.org/) or any other tests framework to mock your class dependencies (your service and your JPA Repository).

You can use these features :

- `@InjectMocks` - Instantiates testing object instance and tries to inject fields annotated with `@Mock` or `@Spy` into private fields of testing object
- `@Mock` - Creates mock instance of the field it annotates

In your test class your have to use `@Mock` to inject "a fake respository" :

```
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
@SpringBootTest
public class CustomerServiceTest {

    @InjectMocks
    private CustomerService testingObject;

    @Mock
    private CustomerRepository customRepository;

    @Rule
    private final GrpcCleanupRule grpcCleanup = new GrpcCleanupRule();

    @BeforeMethod
    public void initMocks(){
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
    }

    @Test
    public void something() throws IOException {

    // inside the testing method you have to define what you mocked object should return.
    // it means mocking the CustomRepository methods

    CustomerDao customer = new CustomerDao(); // fill it with data
    Mockito.when(customRepository.save()).thenReturn(customer);


        // Create a server, add service, start, and register for automatic graceful shutdown.
        grpcCleanup.register(InProcessServerBuilder
                .forName(serverName).directExecutor().addService(new CustomerService()).build().start());

        customerServiceGrpc.CustomerServiceBlockingStub blockingStub = CustomerServiceGrpc.newBlockingStub(
                // Create a client channel and register for automatic graceful shutdown.
                grpcCleanup.register(InProcessChannelBuilder.forName(serverName).directExecutor().build()));

        final CreateCustomerRequest request = CreateCustomerRequest.newBuilder().setFirstName("Simon").setSecondName("Brown").setRole("Product Developer").build();

        final CreateCustomerResponse response = blockingStub.createCustomer(request);
    }

}
```

As your repository and it's methods are mock you customerService should be populated with fake data for test purpose.

**Note :** : It nice to have a naming convention for classes and especially tests classes. A common use is to always give the a suffix of xxTest as i did in the answer

Comment: Thanks for the response but I'm setting up integration tests so don't want to mock part of the software.

Comment: Actually, the suffix xxIT.java is a common naming rule for integration tests. The Maven Failsafe Plugin uses this suffix as the default suffix for integration tests: http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-failsafe-plugin/examples/inclusion-exclusion.html

Comment: You actually have to! Those beans are an injected dependencies that at some point have to be mocked.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to answer without being able to read stacktraces. I would start investigating this problem by looking at the spring context configuration classes. Maybe some of them are missing at the runtime of your integration test.

If spring `@Configuration` or other `@Component` classes exist in your application, it might help to load them explicitly with your tests, along with your unexpectedly null-value `CustomerRepository`:

```
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
@SpringBootTest(classes = {AppConfig.class, CustomerRepository.class })
public class CustomerServiceIT {
```

This might not solve it, but maybe reveals some error messages that help you to investigate the problem.